# CSS Fade Effect on Psudo Element Changes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a new designer. Here is some highlighted part of my code.
HTML:

```
<span data-text = 'XLappy' id = 'copytext'></span>
```

CSS:

```
#copytext::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
}
```

Javascript:

```
var copytext = document.getElementById("copytext");
copytext.addEventListener("click", function(){
  copytext.setAttribute("data-text", "copied");
});
```

now i want to add fading effect when the `XLappy` text convert into `copied` . i don't know how to do it. please help me for that. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach can be fine, but if something can be done in CSS, it should be done in CSS. Maximizing CSS is a better idea than handling unnecessary tasks in JS. That's why my solution is to create #copytext:before for "copied" and to toggle class name when the span is clicked.

```css
#copytext:before,
#copytext:after {
  // all common styles and
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  
}

#copytext:before {
  content: "copied";
  opacity: 0;
}

#copytext:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  opacity: 1;
  
}

#copytext.copied:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

#copytext.copied:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Now, you can add/remove "copied" class in Javascript.

```
var copytext = document.getElementById("copytext");
copytext.addEventListener("click", function(){
  copytext.classList.toggle("copied");
  setTimeout(() => {
     copytext.classList.toggle("copied");  
  }, 2000)
});
```

I suggest you use "-" to separate words for class and id names like "copy-text", and use camel case in JS like copyText, and don't use id unless you have to.